# Debugging a UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibezierpath

I'm struggling to display a `UIBezierPath` that I generate in code, so in my attempt to debug it, I want to print the coordinates it is plotted on. I can't find this technique anywhere. Can someone share this, given the code below?

Thanks

```
UIBezierPath* beizerPath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[beizerPath2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 167)];    
[beizerPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 40)]; 
[beizerPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 70)];    
[beizerPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 30)];    
[beizerPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320, 30)];    
[beizerPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320, 167)];    
[beizerPath2 closePath];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [beizerPath2 CGPath];

//print Bezier/Path co-ordinates here.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "co-ordinates it is plotted on."  You can get the minimum bounding rectangle for a path with the -bounds method.

When you are debugging and want to use NSLog(), also don't overlook the very helpful NSString macros, such as NSStringFromCGRect(), e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect([path bounds]));
```

If I misunderstood your question, please clarify.

Comment: I think what you're asking is nonsensical.  A path is a vector object that can contain infinite key (i.e. turning) points (consider, for example, a path containing a circle).  Until the path is painted all you can have is an abstract representation, though as I indicated you *can* get the minimum bounding rect.  Maybe you should explain what problem you are trying to debug - you might be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: yeah i figured this may be the case, and the defined points (above) disapear into the shape.